# .NET Consumer/Producer (Queue)

Tags: .net, locking, queue, consumer, producer

I'm new at .NET/Threads and I'd like to know if anyone can help me on this exercise. I need to replace the comments in order to make it work without locking the threads:

```
private Queue<int> queue;

public void ConsumeFunc(){
    while (true){
        // 1
        while (/* 2 */){
        // 3
        }
        int element = queue.Dequeue();
        // 4
        Console.WriteLine("Consume element: " + element);
        Thread.Sleep(new Random((int)DateTime.Now.Ticks).Next(0, 2) * 1000);
    }
}

private void ProduceFunc(){
    while (true) {
        // 1
        queue.Enqueue(DateTime.Now.Millisecond);
        // 2
        // 3
        Thread.Sleep(new Random((int)DateTime.Now.Ticks).Next(0, 2) * 1000);
    }
}
```

I managed this but it's not completed

```
public void ConsumerFunc(){
    while (true){
        Monitor.PulseAll(queue);    // 1
        while (queue.Count == 0){   /* 2 */
            Monitor.Wait(queue);    // 3
        }
        int element = queue.Dequeue();
        lock (queue)    // 4
        Console.WriteLine("Consume element: " + element);
        Thread.Sleep(new Random((int)DateTime.Now.Ticks).Next(0, 2) * 1000);
    }
}


public void ProducerFunc(){
    while (true) {
        lock (queue)    // 1
        queue.Enqueue(DateTime.Now.Millisecond);
        Monitor.PulseAll(queue);    // 2
        // 3 ???
        Thread.Sleep(new Random((int)DateTime.Now.Ticks).Next(0, 3) * 1000);
    }
}
```

and gives the following error:
***Object synchronization method was called from an unsynchronized block of code***,
on `Monitor.PulseAll(queue);`

Comment: +1 for demonstrating an attempt to solve the problem before asking for help.  Really neatly asked question!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than fighting to implement the synchronization yourself, take a look at [BlockingCollection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267312.aspx). It handles all the synchronization for you, and will perform better than anything you can create using the `Queue` class and `Monitor`.

There are plenty of examples in the .NET documentation, here on Stack Overflow, and elsewhere. You might find my article useful: http://www.informit.com/guides/content.aspx?g=dotnet&seqNum=821

Comment: If the goal is to build a queue, you might as well use the ConcurrentQueue: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267265.aspx

Comment: @Mathias: `BlockingCollection` is a more general interface that, by default, uses `ConcurrentQueue` as its backing store. I've yet to run across a case where it's better to use `ConcurrentQueue` by itself.